# Rsync between 2 servers with different OS versions

Tags: rsync

I is it possible to Rsync data between two servers running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS? Or they have to be of the exact operating system like Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `rsync` data between those two servers. They do not have to be the same exact operating system.

In fact the important thing is the version of `rsync` you are using, you could use `rsync` also between different *nix systems such as OSX and Ubuntu